# How do I know if a BLE characteristic is encrypted or not without reading it?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I have 1 manager and 1 peripheral.
At peripheral side, I sent a characteristic with `CBCharacteristicProperties.notifyEncryptionRequired` and `CBCharacteristicProperties.indicateEncryptionRequired` properties,
with this line:

```
char = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: charId, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue: 0b1100000000), value: nil, permissions: [CBAttributePermissions.readEncryptionRequired, CBAttributePermissions.writeEncryptionRequired])
```

but when I read at central side it only gives me

0b0000110000

This translates to `notify` and `indicate` properties.
Why doesn't it gives me 0b1100000000? is there something I'm missing?

what I'm trying to do is to check if the value I'm searching for is encrypted or not without pairing.

When I tried to read a value, if it is encrypted, I need to pair. A pairing dialogue will appear. Because the pairing dialogue appears, I know that it is encrypted. I want to know if a characteristic is encrypted or not without seeing the dialogue.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple does not provide any API so the app can know if it talks in a secure way or not with the peripheral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that I once saw a service record in nRF connect which directly showed me that a service was encrypted. But I don't know how they did it. The stack behind it was BlueZ on linux. I think it is *possible* to mark it in a service record.

Moreover, I can tell you that most devices do not do this. I am implementing firmware on a headset CSR controller. The stack on it does just not provide the API to do this. Since I have the firmware as well as the app under my control I can tell you: With this chip it is not possible to know if the characteristic is encrypted or not. 
And sadly, this chip is wide spread.